# How to get php include_path to work on a custom directory '/var/custom_directory'?

Tags: php, apache, azure, include-path, azure-virtual-machine

I thought php include path was a pretty simple concept. I've done it many times, but now am having trouble getting it to work.

I am running an

> centos 7.1 server on azure with Apache/2.4.6 PHP/5.4.16

When I modify the `include_path` within `php.ini`. The error after restarting apache shows

> Failed opening required 'xfile' (include_path='.:/var/custom_directory')...

The include path is in the proper file format.

I might have an ownership problem.

I can place my files inside the default `usr/share/php` directory and the pages `"include"`. However when I try to put my own directory inside of `/var` they do not.

I have done this before so I do not know why it isn't working now.
I have chowned and chmod these directories and their contents to death. Even mimicing the server that works's directories. Switching ownership to `apache` and giving full grant access just trying to get it to see the file from my `/var/www/html/index.php`

Am I missing something?
Is there something I need to enable or grant access or modify in the `php` or `http.conf` files?

Further information:
This is the only php.ini file included in the system /etc/php.ini

The purpose of the include path is to provide coding / user files behind the firewall.

I don't think this maters, but my vm is in Azure.

Putting something like this

```
include('/var/custom_directory/file.php');
```

Doesn't work as well. Why?

Comment: What is the include_path?

Comment: The include path is a configuration setting within your php.ini file. For instance on my centos 7.1 it is located /etc/php.ini

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: To put files in a secure location behind /www

Comment: @Demodave, what I meant was, what is your include_path set to?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, I'd change the way you are doing this and make sure the includes in your PHP files include the path rather than modifying the PHP global include path. The way you are trying to do it could result in problems if you put another site on the same server.

Comment: I understand what you mean. This will be a multi server single domain product.

Answer (score 0):

The `include_path` ini setting *sets* the path, it doesn't add to it, so if you change it you most likely mean to add an extra path, e.g.:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/var/custom_directory"
```

This ensures that both your own `custom_directory` and the standard `/usr/share/php` directory are in the path.

(N.B. On Linux the path seperator is a colon (`:`), on Windows it is a semi-colon (`;`))

### However

You probably don't want to mess around with the php.ini setting, as this will affect all php files. If you put another site on your server which tries to include a file with the same name as one in your custom directory you're going to end up in a confusing situation.

I suggest you either qualify your includes:

```
include('../custom_directory/file.php');
include('/var/custom_directory/file.php');
include(SOURCE_DIR . 'file.php');
```

Or use `set_include_path` at the start of your script:

```
$path = '/var/custom_directory';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Comment: I am aware of this as this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got a quick test to test your requirement.

(environment: CentOs 7.1, Apache/2.4.6 and PHP/5.4.16.)

I created a ‘**includes**’ folder in ‘**`/var/www/`**’ folder besides ‘**`html`**’, shows like:

[image]

Then I set `include_path = ".:/var/www/includes"` in **php.ini**.

In the includes folder I put a test class file named `phpinfo.class.php` with simple code:

```
class phpInfo{
         public function echoinfo(){
                phpinfo(); 
         }
}
```

And in html folder, there is a test PHP file with simple code:

```
require('phpinfo.class.php');
phpInfo::echoinfo();
```

It worked fine to me.

So you may double check your files and path.

---

**update**

I moved the **`includes`** folder under to **`/var/`** beside '**`html`**', and modified the **php.ini**, and still worked fine to me, and the setting of **`include_path`** will be shown in the php runtime environment, we can check the configuration.

[image]

Comment: What does your include_path look like and is it on azure?

Comment: as I showed above, my include_path is ".:/var/includes". and my environment is centOS 7.1 VM built on Azure.

Comment: who owns your directories and what is their permissions?

Comment: what instructions did you follow to install the lamp stack maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: `sudo yum install httpd`, `sudo yum install php`